# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'commentdjango'

Tags: python, django, django-comments

I am trying to add comments to posts on my blog on this guide
https://pypi.org/project/django-comments-dab/ but when doing migrations I get this error, thanks for any help

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have installed the package:
`pip install django-comments-dab`
next step would be to add it on your `INSTALLED_APPS`

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    ...
    'comment',
    ..
)
```

then
`python manage.py migrate comment`

Comment: lol, the guide says about this, so I did it

Comment: can you do a `pip list` ?

Answer (score 0):

I just forgot the comma after the `'comment'` in `INSTALLED_APPS`
..I just didn't get enough sleep today, oh no, I spent so much time on it